# Ember hasMany Relationship not persisting

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I recently got into ember.js development and I'm facing a problem. 
I've two models user.js and userpermissions.js

```
// user
export default DS.Model.extend({
   userName:DS.attr('string'),
   lastName:DS.attr('string'),
   permissionList:DS.hasMany('userpermission',{async:true}),
}); 

// userpermissions
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user:DS.belongsTo('user'),
  permissionName:DS.attr('string'),
  permissionId:DS.attr('string'),  
});
```

I'm trying to set permissions for a user record.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

     selectedPermission: {},
     newUser: {},
     init: function() {
        this.newUser = this.store.createRecord('user');
     },

     addPermission: function() {
        var permission = this.store.createRecord('userpermission');
        permission.set('permissionId', this.get('selectedPermission.id'));
        this.get('newUser').get('permissionList').pushObject(permission);
     }
});
```

Finally save is called for new user.

```
this.get('newuser').save();
```

To persist data to my nodejs back-end. All the userpermissions are recorded as null.
I've tried to search for a solution but couldn't find one.
Could anyone point me what i am doing wrong, or what is the solution
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this by adding user Serializer and EmbeddedRecordsMixin

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
attrs: {
permissionList: { embedded: 'always' },

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you seem to be saving the Permission record...

You don't need to worry about tables, but you will need to save both models. Ember can't presume to know the required order of operation when it comes to saving the two records via your API, so you must save each explicitly, in the correct order.

So try modifying your controller as such:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

     selectedPermission: {},
     newUser: {},
     init: function() {
        this.newUser = this.store.createRecord('user');
     },

     addPermission: function() {
        var permission = this.store.createRecord('userpermission');
        permission.set('permissionId', this.get('selectedPermission.id'));
        this.get('newUser').get('permissionList').pushObject(permission);

        permission.save();
     }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The way we make hasMany connections.

```
    // user
    export default DS.Model.extend({
       userName:DS.attr('string'),
       lastName:DS.attr('string'),
    }); 

    // permissions
    export default DS.Model.extend({
      permissionName: DS.attr('string)
    });

    // userpermissions
    export default DS.Model.extend({
      user:DS.belongsTo('user'),
      permission:DS.belongs('permission')
    });
```

By having a third table.

About saving: [Set multiple data with Ember and make it persist on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910331/set-multiple-data-with-ember-and-make-it-persist-on-firebase/29917787#29917787)

```
user.save().then(function(user) {
  permission.save().then(function(permission) {
      userpermission.save().then(function() {
            // Connection done
      });
  });
}, failure);
```